# awslabs/auto-check-in-appでどのパラメーターを使ったらよいかわからない

Tags: aws, bash

以下のサンプルを実行しようとしたらステップ4でエラーがでました。

https://github.com/awslabs/auto-check-in-app

4. Run the following command `./register-operator.sh <operator E-mail address>` - Note: Specify the applicable AWS Region and AWS CloudFormation stack name in the script.

> syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Note: Specify the applicable AWS Region and AWS CloudFormation stack name in the script.と記載されていたので、operatorにスタック名、addressにリージョン名を入れoperator E-mail address部分をauto-check-in-app name@mail.com us-west-2に変更して実行しました。

もしご存知の方がいましたらアドバイス頂けましたら嬉しいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「operator E-mail address にリージョン名とスタック名を入れる」←これは README に書かれていることと違います。具体的にどのようなことをなさったのか、質問文に書いてくださいませんでしょうか？（「編集」から質問文に追記できます）

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。初心者で英語にも自身がない中で申し訳ないです。ご指摘頂きました内容を踏まえて質問文を変更させて頂きました。

Answer (score 0):

質問者さんのやり方はこのスクリプトの想定された使われ方とは異なります。スクリプトの[この行](https://github.com/awslabs/auto-check-in-app/blob/8cd9ddd4744eb8b93093024e8e47922612bf2659/source/frontend/register-operator.sh#L9)に実行例が載っているので見てみてください。

README に "Note: ～" と書かれているのは、このスクリプト中で[定義されている](https://github.com/awslabs/auto-check-in-app/blob/8cd9ddd4744eb8b93093024e8e47922612bf2659/source/frontend/register-operator.sh#L3-L4)変数 `REGION` と `STACK_NAME` をご自身の環境に合わせて適宜書き換えてね、ということです。

なので実際にやるべき内容は、

1. `REGION` と `STACK_NAME` の内容を適宜合わせる。
2. `./register-admin-user.sh user@example.com` の形式で実行する。

です。